# How to convert Base64 to String in logic app inline code (Javascript)

Tags: node.js, azure-logic-apps, inline-code

**Summary**: Logic app inline code (which uses NodeJS) is missing [Buffer class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSTjQ.png).

**Detailed**: I am trying to trigger a logic app when some content is pushed into SFTP. I want to add some meta-data and save the details in the cosmos DB.

The **issue is**, The name of the file is received as a base64 encoded string in the inline code and Buffer is not available to parse it.

I even tried to create a set variable step (and decode filename there) but I am unable
to pass this variable to the inline code step. (Not supported)

The final option would be to use cloud functions instead of inline code which I am trying to avoid.

Looking for a workaround for conversion.

[Logic App error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSTjQ.png)
[link to ms doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-add-run-inline-code)

1. Doesn't support require() statements
2. Doesn't work with variables

Answer (score 1):

Inline code can only perform the simplest `Javascript` operations, we may not be able to use `Buffer`.

As for passing the base64 encoded string, you can put it in [Compose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#compose-action) first, and then pass it in the inline code.

I suggest you use the built-in base64 related methods in the Azure logic app first.

[image]

If this does not meet your needs, you can create an [Azure function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-get-started?pivots=programming-language-javascript) and then [call it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-azure-functions#add-existing-functions-to-logic-apps) in the Azure logic app.